# Python : pygame.key.get_pressed not working

Tags: python, pygame, keypress

I know that there are already some questions posted regarding the same issue but the solutions proposed didn't help me.

I want to monitor the state of the arrow keys (pressed/not pressed) at any given time so I have the following code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
a=[0,0,0,0]

while True:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        a[0]=1;
    else:
        a[0]=0;
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        a[1]=1;
    else:
        a[1]=0;

    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        a[2]=1;
    else:
        a[2]=0;

    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        a[3]=1;
    else:
        a[3]=0;

    print a
    pygame.event.pump()
```

So, basically, I keep printing a list **a** of 4 numbers, each representing an arrow key (1 if pressed, 0 otherwise).

However all values of the list are always zero even if i keep pressing the arrow keys for long.

I also tried printing the whole **keys** array : Turns out all entries are zeros again, no matter which keys I press and for how long

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks !

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I am using python 2.7 on windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, if you haven't actually created a pygame window, no events will be passed to pygame and therefore the result of `pygame.key.get_pressed()` won't update. Pygame only receives events on the currrent pygame window. You're probably looking at the console, which is not receiving events. I added `pygame.display.set_mode((100,100))` just after `pygame.init()` and then ran the program. I clicked inside the pygame window. Then the console start displaying the appropriate ones in the console.

Also suggest adding something to pause the loop like `time.sleep` and something like event checking to break out of it. (proper exiting)

Comment: Thank you, that did it. Actually, I wasn't interested in creating a game, I just wanted to monitor the arrow keys for different purposes and I was told that the best way was to use pygame. I didn't know I would have to create a window for it to work...

Comment: Tkinter may be helpful, but I'm not sure, you probably still have to create a root window. I'm not sure of any ways to monitor the arrow keys with just the console.